# Prepopulated Form causing issues for DbContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

After doing lots of debugging, I've narrowed down as to why my `dbContext` update does not work.

I have a script that runs on `Page_Load` that will populate a form based on the query string `category_Id` which is the primary key of my table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Populate Edit Fields
        if (Request.QueryString["categoryId"] != null)
        {
            CategoryDAL categoryDAL = new CategoryDAL();
            RecipeCategory myCategory = new RecipeCategory();

            try
            {
                addDiv.Attributes["class"] = "hidden";
                editDiv.Attributes["class"] = "display";

                int categoryToGet = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["categoryId"]);
                myCategory = categoryDAL.GetCategory(categoryToGet);

                tbEditCategoryName.Text = myCategory.Category_Name;
                tbEditCategoryDescription.Text = myCategory.Description;

                ddlEditCategoryGroupList.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(myCategory.CatGroup_Id);
                ddlEditCategoryGroupList.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                updateStatus.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in";
                updateStatus.Visible = true;
                lblStatus.Text = "Could not get Category Info, please try again.";
            }
        }
```

This is my script that runs when the edit_Button is clicked, it should update the row in the database and redirect to the viewCategories page.

```
    protected void btnEditCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["categoryId"] != null)
        {
            CategoryDAL categoryDAL = new CategoryDAL();
            RecipeCategory myCategory = new RecipeCategory();

            try
            {
                int categoryToEdit = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["categoryId"]);

                myCategory.Category_Name = tbEditCategoryName.Text;
                myCategory.Description = tbEditCategoryDescription.Text;
                myCategory.CatGroup_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEditCategoryGroupList.SelectedValue);

                try
                {
                    bool editStatus = categoryDAL.EditCategory(categoryToEdit, myCategory);

                    if (editStatus)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["editStatus"] = "Successful";
                        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/ManageCategories.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblEditStatus.Text = "Unable to update category, please try again";
                        lblEditStatus.CssClass = "alert-danger";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblEditStatus.Text = Convert.ToString(ex);
                    lblEditStatus.CssClass = "alert-danger";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                updateStatus.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in";
                updateStatus.Visible = true;
                lblStatus.Text = "Invalid categoryId.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            updateStatus.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in";
            updateStatus.Visible = true;
            lblStatus.Text = "Nothing to update.";
        }
    }
```

And this is in my DALayer which holds the functions that has anything to do with categories.

```
    public bool EditCategory(int categoryToEdit, RecipeCategory newCategoryInfo)
    {
        RecipeXchangeDBContext dbContext = new RecipeXchangeDBContext();
        RecipeCategory myCategory = new RecipeCategory();
        bool status = false;

        myCategory = (from c in dbContext.RecipeCategories
                      where c.Category_Id == categoryToEdit
                      select c).First();

        myCategory.Category_Name = newCategoryInfo.Category_Name;
        myCategory.Description = newCategoryInfo.Description;
        myCategory.CatGroup_Id = newCategoryInfo.CatGroup_Id;

        try
        {
            if (dbContext.SaveChanges() == 1)
                status = true;
            else
                status = false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

For some reason, whenever I try to update a row with a prepopulated form, the code will always return 0 from `dbContext.SaveChanges()` and does not update the row in the database.

**Note:** if I do not populate the form, it works perfectly as normal.

Comment: You don't need to populate the fields in page_load. ASP.NET viewstate maintains the values of controls during postbacks. Is there any specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Err, cause I have a page before this that displays all categories with an edit button which links it to this page with category_id in the url as a QueryString.

On this page it will then use the category_id to populate the form to make it easy for users to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` doesn't just run the first time the page is loaded, it runs every time the page is loaded, including when the user submits the form. The result is that you're overwriting the user's input before saving it.

In this case, since you're using regular browser navigation to go to a specific category page, you can just check `Page.IsPostBack` in `Page_Load` and not set anything in that case.